# have 20% odds of Ving

Tags: collocations

I'd like to know if the following sentences are OK. Do they have the same meaning?

> a. Senior women have 20% odds of developing the disease.

> b. Senior women have 1/4 odds of developing the disease.

> c. Senior women have 1:4 odds of developing the disease.

> d. Senior women have 1-in-5 odds of developing the disease.

Comment: 1 in 4 is not the same thing as 20%, to begin with.  I don't know if that's part of the question you were asking or if it's just a typo.

Comment: I didn't write "1 in 4."

Comment: That's what "1/4" means.

Comment: I found this: 4/1 can be calculated as 1 / (4 + 1) = 0.20 – There is a 20% chance that the event will happen

Comment: This is more math than English, "1/4" means "one part out of four" (i.e., 25%); it does not mean "one part versus four parts."

Comment: 1/4 is not the same as 1:4. 1/4 = 25%. 1:4 (said, "one to four") means 20%. Also, 4/1 = 4. This might be more appropriate to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are maths issues.

"Odds" are used in gambling, as they are convenient for calculating the size of a bet<sup>*</sup>. Don't use "odds" outside of gambling.  Use "probability" or "chance"

Secondly 1/4 doesn't equal 20%.  1/4 =25% and 1/5=20%

> Senior women have a 20% chance of developing the disease

(As odds, a bookie would lay 4:1 as a fair bet on a woman developing the disease, but betting on diseases is not a common game!)

*And make it harder for punters to realise how unfair horse racing gambling is.

Comment: I found this: 4/1 can be calculated as 1 / (4 + 1)  = 0.20 – There is a 20% chance that the event will happen.

Comment: @Apollyon In usual mathematical notation, 4/1 = 4, and 1/4 = 0.25, and the latter equals 25/100, or 25%.

Comment: Odds of 4:1 mean that the bookie lays £4 for every £1 the punter places. If the game is fair, then there would be a 1/5 chance of winning. In fact in a game where the bookie offers 4:1 the actual chance of winning is usually less than 20%.  This is how a bookie makes a profit.

Comment: In ordinary speech, we might say, at least in Britain 'My brother's car got struck by lightning, then his mother-in-law won the lottery, and finally he won the Nobel Peace Prize. What are the odds of that happening?'.